# Configuring nginx to use basic authentication?

Tags: nginx

I have nginx working fine, I would like to add basic auth:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  server_tokens off;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 15;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
  open_file_cache max=100;
  log_format octohost '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_request_id"';
  access_log /dev/stdout;
  error_log /dev/stdout info;

  server {
      auth_basic                  "Restricted";
      auth_basic_user_file        /etc/nginx/sites-available/.htpasswd;
  }
}

daemon off;
```

However, it is not requesting a username/password. The .htpasswd file is simply "test:test" ... what am I missing on this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [`auth_basic`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html) directive needs to be inside of a `location` section.  For example:

```
server {
  location / {
    auth_basic           "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;
 }
}
```

Comment: This did not do anything.